# Backbone Router -- load data

Tags: backbone.js

EDIT: Got it working, but it seems wrong.

I ending up adding a listener to the sync event on the main app view, then render a player. I also added a global variable `PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayer`.

Am I going about this the wrong way? What is the correct way to do this? Is there a reason I can't use `reset: true` and then listen for the reset event? (It doesn't work)

ROUTER:

```
// js/router.js
var PgaPlayersApp = PgaPlayersApp || {};

var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes:{
      'player/:id': 'loadPlayer'
    },
    loadPlayer: function(id)
    {
        PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayer.set('id', id);
        PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayer.fetch();    
    }   
});

PgaPlayersApp.Router = new Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

VIEW:

```
//js/views/app.js

var PgaPlayersApp = PgaPlayersApp || {};

PgaPlayersApp.AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '#pga_players_profile_app',
    initialize: function()
    {
        this.listenTo(PgaPlayersApp.Players, 'reset', this.addAll);
        this.listenTo(PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayer, 'sync', this.loadPlayer);
        PgaPlayersApp.Players.fetch({reset: true});
    },

    ...

    loadPlayer: function()
    {
        new PgaPlayersApp.PlayerCardView({ model: PgaPlayersApp.CurrentPlayer }).render();
    }

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backbone.js is a library that doesn't really enforce how you'd like to structure your App (Or the relationship between your Controller, Model, Router, etc.)

Below is one of the many ways to do it.

Couple highlights:

1. Router kicks off the fetch process.
2. When model has been fetched, Router then asks the View to render data (Instead of having the View listening to change events from the Model.)

This assumes that PlayerCardView is a "read only" view, as the View doesn't listen to change events from the Model. Depending on your use case, this might not be desirable, so it ultimately depends on how you'd like to handle it.

Here are some sample code:

```
(function (export) { 
    var App = export.App = {};

    // Stores state/current views of the App
    App.state = {};
    App.state.currentPlayer = null;

    // Model containing the player
    App.PlayerModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});

    // Single Player View (Assuming you have a collection view for list of players)
    App.PlayerCardView = Backbone.View.extend({
        model: App.PlayerModel,
        template: _.template('<%= id %>'),
        render: function(parentEl) {
            // Render player
            this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));

            // Append player view to parent container
            if (parentEl) {
                parentEl.append(this.$el);
            }

            return this;
        }

        // Don't forget to clean up as well!
    });

    // Router
    App.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
        routes: {
            'player/:id': 'showPlayer'
        },
        showPlayer: function(id) {
            // Unload current player view, if necessary

            // Construct model
            var player = App.state.currentPlayer = new App.Player({
                id: id
            });

            // Pass model to the new player view
            var view = App.state.currentPlayerView = new App.PlayerCardView({
                model: App.state.currentPlayer
            });

            // At this time, you should probably show some loading indicator as you're fetching data from the server

            // Fetch data
            player.fetch({
                success: function() {
                    // This would be called when data has been fetched from the server.

                    // Render player on screen
                    view.render($('#parentContainerId'));
                }
            });
        }
    });

    // Initializes the App
    App.init = function() {
        // Kick off router
        App.state.router = new App.Router();
        export.Backbone.history.start();
    };
})(window);

// Start the app!
window.App.init();
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/dashk/5770073